# wordpress as HTML interface for database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have several embedded hardware system in the field that update to a server with a central database. My next step is to manage the database through a web interface so records can be viewed and displayed as required.

My plan thus far has been to install AMPPS and wordpress. However I am not sure where to begin when writing custom pages on a wordpress install. I have created the four pages I require but i am now at a loss on how to edit these pages so I can do PHP queries on the database and had users modify some of the records.

If anyone could point me to some wordpress (and PHP) resources that focus on working with wordpress at a deeper level as opposed to customising themes and installing plugins I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress isn't really a DBMS, so you'd have to code all of the functionality yourself.

It sounds like you'd be better off with [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php).

Comment: The interface is to make it easier for user to manipulate the database whilst limiting some of the access they have. We also plan to use it to export structured reports eventually.

Comment: You still need a DBMS, not a blog system.

Comment: I agree that WordPress is not the best solution for this. phpMyAdmin can save SQL queries (reports) and you can create users with different permission levels. If you would like a custom application you should look into PHP frameworks. There is a list of popular frameworks on the [PHP tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info).